# My GORM Primary ID is getting set to an 18 digit number, how can i force this number to start at 1

Tags: go-gorm

I'm using GORM to handle my database operations. My struct is as follows

```golang
type Job struct {
    gorm.Model
    JobID         int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Jobitem       []Jobitem
    SubID         int    `sql:"not null"`
    StartDateTime string `sql:"not null"`
    JobStatus     string `sql:"not null"`
}
```

When I insert into the table using this struct, my primary key is 18 digits long, for example: 399758776912773121

Is it possible to get this id to begin at 1 and increment from there?

Answer (score 1):

You're using both `gorm.Model` and defining your own primary key. So my guess is that gorm automatically thinks you're trying to use [Composite Primary Key](http://gorm.io/docs/composite_primary_key.html), since your struct actually looks like this:

```golang
type Job struct {
    // gorm.Model ↓
    ID            uint `gorm:"primary_key"` // Gorm uses this
    CreatedAt     time.Time
    UpdatedAt     time.Time
    DeletedAt     *time.Time `sql:"index"`
    // gorm.Model ↑

    JobID         int        `gorm:"primary_key"` // And also detects this
    Jobitem       []Jobitem
    SubID         int    `sql:"not null"`
    StartDateTime string `sql:"not null"`
    JobStatus     string `sql:"not null"`
}
```

Long story short, have a look [there for some documentation on `gorm.Model`](http://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#gorm-Model)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Depado, 
It looks like this is built in behavior by the database and not specifically related to GORM. The ID fields are generated using the unique_rowid() function in cockroachdb which is generated by a combination of the timestamp and id of the node executing the insert.